# Run android –livereload ERR_INVALID_RESPONSE

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

Im using ionic 3, and im trying to use the ionic cordova run android --livereload .

When i run ionic cordova run android it works normally but when i run this code i see the error: It was not possible to load the webpage on address http://192.168.25.4:8101/ because: net::ERR_INVALID_RESPONDE .

I already tried a lot of things for 2 days but i couldnt find anything on the web.

Follow the versions im using:

@ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.2
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.20.0
global packages:

cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.1.2 (cordova-lib@8.1.1) 
local packages:

@ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.8
Cordova Platforms  : android 6.3.0 browser 6.0.0
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
System:

ios-deploy : 1.9.2 
ios-sim    : 5.0.8 
Node       : v8.11.1
npm        : 5.6.0 
OS         : macOS High Sierra
Xcode      : Xcode 9.4.1 Build version 9F2000 
I think its a connection error but i couldnt fix it yet.

Comment: Does it work on localhost?

Comment: it works on localhost !

Comment: Are you on an enterprise network or on your local network?

Comment: local network.. i've been trying a lot of things, but without success until now.